# Linear Resolution Principle - First Order Logic

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I have a set of clauses S. I know how the **Linear Resolution Principle** algorithm can find the unsatisfiability of the set , but i dont understand how it finds if the the set is satisfable. How it happens ?

ps: is it somehow connected to the fact that the input resolution algorithm
is incomplete ?

Comment: It is not *completeness*: for FOL the *Completeness of the Resolution Principle* holds: "A set $S$ of clauses is *unsatisfiable* if and only if there is a deduction of the empty clause from $S$." 
 The issue id about [undecidability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Completeness_and_undecidability) of FOL: there are formulas that are *satisfiable* only in infinite domain.

Comment: See the post [validity-undecidable-in-first-order-logic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/612681/validity-undecidable-in-first-order-logic).

Comment: Thanks. And how the Linear Resolution Principle proves that a set is satisfable ? If you reply as an answer i can vote you :)

Comment: Why, Mauro, the fact that it doesnt produce an empty clause implies that the set is satisfiable ?

Comment: You are right Mauro. What i havent clearly understood is the proof of the "completeness of the resolution principle", that is based on the Herbrand Theorem (which i know, thanks  to your past explanation of this theorem to me)

Comment: There are many versione of the *Completeness Th*, because there are many proof systems for FOL. But every one must be *complete*.

Comment: This is mindblowing. What do you intend for :  "many proof systems" ?

Comment: See [FOL: Deductive systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Deductive_systems).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not *completeness*.

We have the *Completeness of the Resolution Principle*:

> "A set $S$ of clauses is *unsatisfiable* if and only if there is a deduction of the *empty clause* from $S$."

The issue is about *undecidability* of FOL: there are formulas that are satisfiable only in infinite domains.

When we apply the resolution proof procedure, we have three possible cases: if
the procedure halts without producing the empty clause, then the set $S$ is *satisfiable*. If $S$ is *unsatisfiable*, the procedure halts with the empty clause.

If, on the other hand, $S$ is satisfiable only in an infinite domain, then the procedure does not halt.

Thus, if we can **not** deduce the *empty clause* from $S$, then the set $S$ is **not** unsatisfiable, i.e. it is *satisfiable*.

Comment: Suppose that we have a set and we use the Resolution Principle many times; at a point no more different clauses are produced. The Resolution Principle then states that the set is satisfiable. But, what the dimostration of this ? (I have understood the "Completeness of the Resolution Principle" , but i havent understood why it works in this case)